# Magnetic field between two rings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, magnetostatics

Two rings are placed parallel atop each other along an axis with a distance $\epsilon$ which is much smaller than the radius of both rings a. Through one of the rings there is a current I and through the other the same current but in the opposite direction. Exactly between the rings along the axis the magnetic field is zero and at points far away as well, so there must be a point along the axis between 0 and $\infty$ where the magnetic field is at a maximum. Where is this point?

Edit: can you show me how to find this point with a calculation?

Comment: The field is roughly max. at the surface of either of the conductors if they are thin. If they are modeled by an infinitely thin current, then the field is divergent at the position of the current.

Answer (score 1):

The field B(z) on the axis of a circular current loop is well known.
Differentiate f(z)=B(z-e/2)-B(z+e/2), and set that equal to zero.
Expand the denominator to first order in ez/(z^2+a^2).
The answer I got is z=(+/-) a/2.